# How to block/delete inactivate/fake Instagram followers?

Tags: instagram

I have a bunch of Instagram followers who no longer are active. Is there a way to detect followers who have not liked one of your last 10 posts and block them?

Comment: You could script something like that using the API.

Comment: @TomWoodward if you know how to do this, you might want to create an example and post it as an answer.

Comment: @TomWoodward I think the API is under tight restrictions now. You have to have a real app idea I believe.

Comment: Yeah. Even before these changes, It'd require full oauth etc. to do it. I'll put it on my list of things to play with if time allows.

Answer (score 1):

There's a great and thorough tool named [IGExorcist.](http://www.igexorcist.com/igexorcist.php)

It allows you to check for ghost followers on Instagram, which are the inactive or spam accounts that follow you. It works by cross-checking your followers against accounts you’re following to gauge interaction over the past 300 days.